# Removing a View from same view. Is it good practice.?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have added following piece of code in a view.

```
- (IBAction)accept_clicked:(id)sender {
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
    self.view = nil;
}
```

Once accept is clicked, I have removed the own view like this. It worked fine, anyhow is it fine to do like this or It should be removed from another view(parent)?

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am trying to remove the view fully. After accept clicked I don't want that view anymore.

Comment: Why you are removing your super view ..... ?

Comment: @VakulSaini This view is like a notification view, once accepted I have to remove that view and show the parent view who added this.

Comment: Well, thats ok how you do it. There aren't any issues with that. Just make sure that all subviews of the view are also deallocated accordingly.

Comment: @anka I am new to IOS, In windows, If we delete a window from its same instance it will crash. That's why I got doubt, how it is working here.

Comment: I see, another solution would be to provide a protocol and delegate so you can trigger the "close" or "remove" action from the delegate, but basically it would result into same same behavior but it is a little bit cleaner.

Comment: @user1587011 - Try to remove yor subView of view from super view instead of removing self.View. Like if you added [self.View addSubView: notificationView]; then remove it like [notificationView removewFromSuperView];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do this (with `self.view`) - it doesn't looks good and you might face difficult to find problems. `self.view` is the main view associated with an `UIViewController`. So this view to be visible on the screen, you must have shown it somehow: either pushing it to a `UINavigationController` or presenting it modally with `-presentViewController:animated:completion:` (IOS5+) or `- presentModalViewController:animated:`. Showing a view by instantiating a view controller and adding its view to the current view controller's view is not a good practice also:

```
//Not good
MyViewController *mvc = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
[self.view addSubView:mvc.view];
```

In your particular case I suppose you are showing some terms and conditions (or something similar) and have an accept and deny button, your best solution would be to present your view controller from somewhere, implement a delegate method, so the presenting view controller can have the result and then in your `-accept_clicked:` method to use either `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]` or `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:]` (IOS5+),